# How can I update my variable(s) every time an external file is shared?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I tap on a file in a mail and share it with my app (I think it's called an intend?) the app opens, shows the correct view and displays the information I want.
When the app stays open in the background and I redo the process nothing changes.
Instead it should update the variables with the information of the new file.

Here is a bit of code from my app:

@main swift file:

```
    FirstView()
    .onOpenURL { url in
       if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
             let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
             let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
             guard let type = UTType(filenameExtension: url.pathExtension) else {
                   network.receivedError(error: Exception.fileTypeNotSupported.localizedDescription)
                   return
             }
             url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

             ActionHandler.shared.openExternalFile(fileData: fileData, fileName: fileName, fileType: type)
     }
```

Welcome View:

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
@StateObject private var actionHandler = ActionHandler.shared

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundColor(AppColors.accentColor)
        Text("AppTitle").font(Font.custom("Pacifico-Regular", size: 40)).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(AppColors.accentColor)
        NavigationLink(destination: Layout(navIndex: 2,
                                           content: { DocView(fileData: actionHandler.getFileData(), fileName: actionHandler.getFileName(), fileType: actionHandler.getFileType()) }),
                       isActive: $actionHandler.showExternalFile) { EmptyView() }
    }
}
```

}

and a snippet from the ActionHandler:

```
class ActionHandler: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = ActionHandler()

  @Published var showExternalFile: Bool = false {
    willSet(newValue) {
        Log.shared.debug("Show external file: \(newValue)")
    }
  }

  func openExternalFile(fileData: Data?, fileName: String, fileType: UTType) {
    self.fileData = fileData
    self.fileName = fileName
    self.fileType = fileType
    showExternalFile = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { self.showExternalFile = false }
  }
```

The DocView gets called the first time with the correct parameters.
Those parameters don't seem to get "refreshed" when I redo the process with a different file. I am guessing that's probably because the DocView was already loaded.
The parameters should be the ones of the new file I shared with the app.